# Tool for monitoring a virtual machine remotely

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu-usage, resource-monitor

We are running VirtualBox and phpVirtualBox for a few test servers, recently we have had stability problems on some of them, does anyone know of any remote monitoring tool (open source/free prefered) that can monitor Virtual Machines, a web (php) interface would be nice. It is normal Windows machines (mostly) so I guess some form of SNMP software would work?

Comment: Could you specify if guest and/or host machines are Windows, and if you want to know the host machine status or the well being of the virtualized servers.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org) for monitoring servers. The community has lots of information on how to configure Nagios with Windows servers, using NSClient++. [This guide](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html) offers the information you need for Windows servers specifically.